# Georeferencing Data Points?

Tags: coordinate-system, new-zealand

I am looking for a coordinate system of New Zealand. I just have x/y coordinates of the south island, but no further information on the map. I have tried several systems and nothing did fit the data points.

A scatter plot of the points has shown that the points are even mirrored. The values do look like below.

```
7340311 46446451
9176667 45905000
7379577 46435685
7373889 46465000
7410593 46700702
10273967 43753542
7419167 46463056
7419787 46703207
6768776 48687156
9497410 44102852
8673500 47756069
6754167 48717222
8255278 46105833
6781457 48672920
6715970 48729233
10603611 44749722
```

[image: example]

Comment: I played around with them a bit. I think the points are in decimeters or centimeters or decimal yards (I tried the older NZ South Island grid). Adding a decimal point either one or 2 places from the right resizes the data so that it will fit on the island at least. I still couldn't make them work even with using the numbers as northing,easting.

Comment: Would help if you included the coordinates *as text* rather than an image, then we don't all have to type it in with all the problems that might occur.

Comment: Which projections have you tried already, and do you know which is easting and which is northing?

Comment: I tried several UTM like 1S, 2S, 59S and the 60S. I also tried the New Zealand Transverse Mercerator (NZTM) and other coordinate systems, proposed by this page: http://apps.linz.govt.nz/coordinate-conversion/. I also georefernced a NZ South Island Map on this unknown coordinate system and I could provide some NZTM or World Geodatic System approximations, if this would help. I have no further information, neither easting or northing, nor meta data. I have attached the picture of the scatter plot

Comment: Perhaps try Spatial Adjustment? In ArcMap, there is a Spatial Adjustment toolbar that allows you to specify links between your data points and their corresponding real location, then adjust the data itself. It's hard to tell which projection would be best, since we have no idea how these coordinates were created, but I would try with a transverse mercator, or maybe even plain WGS84 (4326).

Comment: @FSimardGIS: EPSG:4326 coordinates for NZ would be like -43.53,172.620278 for Christchurch and -36.840556,174.74 for Auckland - quite different.

Comment: @ulicious: from your scatterplot it definitely looks like you have the coordinates somehow mirrored as the two protrusions on the left are IMHO Christchurch and Dunedin so they should be on the right.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I can move single data points to their right positions, but I have a Data Set with more than 600.000 points. Is there a way to move all of them at once (without my computer crashing) and warp their positions s.t. it fits the map?

Comment: With Spatial Adjustment, you should be able to link some points, then at the end, select "Adjust" to warp the whole dataset at once. I don't know if your machine can handle it, but it could be worth a try, since we have no idea which coordinate system it is. As @Juhele says, it is definitely not WGS84, and it does not fit with any registered transverse mercator projections either, so the data will have to be warped against a know projection, maybe with NZTM could work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to fix the issue.

1. I have used a linear model in Excel, first, to convert the coordinates into the NZTM system. Here, I used Google Maps coordinate approximations of very noticeable points like crossroads etc as input.
2. I plotted the calculated data with the new coordinates on a base map and used the spatial adjustment tool (rubbersheet), as suggested by @FSimardGIS, for the fine-tuning. The result is pretty accurate and I think close enough to further work with.

[image: result]

Comment: And just to complete the answer: a friend of mine even cracked the code to transform it into WGS:

x: 180 - x_location / 10^6
y: -90 + y_location / 10^6